# Was there any name for electrical sparks before 'electric' and its related terms were invented?

Tags: electricity

Was there any name for electrical sparks before 'electric' and its related terms were invented as a result of [De Magnete (1600)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymology_of_electricity)?

Like, if people were in a dark room, and saw a [triboelectric spark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect#Sparks%20triboelectric%20spark), what would they have called it, if anything?

Possibly connected to [When did static electricity become a common occurrence?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/19211/when-did-static-electricity-become-a-common-occurrence) and [Since when do humans know about electric charge?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/since-when-do-humans-know-about-electric-charge)

[Possibly](http://electricity.how-old-is-this.com/), sparks were unknown before the discovery of electricity?

No... There's [scintilla](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scintilla), Latin for Spark, but that's only appeared in English from 1700s... Too new? But then again, English wasn't used for scientific writing at first. It was  Latin that ruled, initially.

Comment: Sparks of other kinds were known before.  If they saw an electric spark but didn't know about electricity, they would have used the same name as for other sparks.  OED has Old English "spærca" dating approximately from the year 725.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar - Oh, right. And if you got shocked by static, you'd just call it by the local word for 'shock'...